# Como listar apenas o nome das pastas existentes em um determinado diretório?

Tags: c#, .net, diretório

Como posso fazer para listar apenas o nome de uma pasta que está dentro de uma pasta raiz?

Exemplo:

```
Pasta raiz C:/Downloads

SubPastas: Teste/ Teste 2
```

[image: Mostrando pastas]

Na minha DLL eu consigo listar as pastas porém com seu caminho completo, gostaria apenas de listar o nome das subpastas:

No caso apenas `Teste` e `Teste 2`

Segue código:

```
 private void carregarFolders()
    {
        try
        {
            string caminho = @"C:/Downloads";
            ddlFolders.DataSource = Directory.GetDirectories(caminho);
            ddlFolders.DataValueField = "";
            ddlFolders.DataTextField = "";
            ddlFolders.DataBind();
            ddlFolders.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(string.Empty, string.Empty));


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

[image: Resultado na tela]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível, usando LINQ, mapear cada caminho completo para uma instância de **[`DirectoryInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)** e, a partir desta instância, obter apenas o "nome final" do diretório usando a propriedade **[`Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.name(v=vs.110).aspx)**.

```
var source = Directory.GetDirectories(caminho)
                      .Select(c => new DirectoryInfo(c).Name)
                      .ToList();

ddlFolders.DataSource = source;
```

Answer (score 3):

A forma que lhe dará melhor performance:

```
try {
    var dirs = new List<string();
    foreach (var dir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(caminho)) dirs.Add(dir.Substring(dir.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1));
} catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex) {
    //faça algo útil aqui ou retire esse catch
} catch (PathTooLongException ex) {
    //faça algo útil aqui ou retire esse catch
}
ddlFolders.DataSource = dirs;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/GetDirectories.cs).

Nunca capture uma exceção para fazer nada, especialmente para lançá-la novamente.